# Help with complicated MySQL query

Tags: mysql, query

I asked an earlier question about modeling  [MySQL data modeling help](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2870/mysql-data-modeling-help). The recommendation was the diagram labeled Multiple Tables for Role and Sponsor. [image: Multiple Tables for Role and Sponsor]

Now I'm trying to write the queries and struggling. It's the point where I kept giving up and looking at maybe easier database models, but now I know that won't work and I need some advice.

When I have an event_id and a user_id, I need to check whether this leader is allowed to edit this event. They are allowed if

- Are the user_id and event_id is in the user_event_role table?
- If this event also has a project_id, is the user in the user_project_role table for the project that runs this event?
- Is the user in the user_organization_role table for the organizations that sponsor this project (check the project_sponsor table)?
- Is the user in the user_organization_role table for the organizations that sponsor this event (check the event_sponsor table)?

If this user_id is found in any of these leader positions for the event, project, or organizations sponsoring the event or project, then it's okay for this user/leader to edit.

I'm not sure how to write such a complicated query. The following query insists that the user_id be present in all three user_role tables when it only has to be present in one.

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM user AS u
JOIN user_event_role AS uer ON (uer.user_id=u.id)
JOIN user_project_role AS upr ON (upr.user_id=uer.id)
JOIN user_organization_role AS uor ON (uor.user_id=upr.user_id)
JOIN event_sponsor AS es ON (es.organization_id=uor.organization_id)
JOIN project_sponsor AS ps ON (ps.project_id=upr.project_id)
WHERE
  uer.term_to >= CURRENT_DATE() AND
  upr.term_to >= CURRENT_DATE() AND
  uor.term_to >= CURRENT_DATE() AND
  u.netid='{$netid}'
```

Do I need to do something as complicated as this union:

```
  SELECT count(*)
  FROM user AS u
  JOIN user_event_role AS uer ON (uer.user_id=u.id)
  WHERE
    uer.event_id=$event_id AND
    uer.term_to >= CURRENT_DATE() AND
    uer.role != 'volunteer' AND
    u.netid='{$netid}'
UNION
  SELECT count(*)
  FROM user AS u
  JOIN user_project_role AS upr ON (upr.user_id=u.id)
  JOIN event AS e ON (e.project_id=upr.project_id)
  WHERE
    e.id=$event_id AND
    upr.term_to >= CURRENT_DATE() AND
    u.netid='{$netid}'                      
UNION
  SELECT count(*)
  FROM user AS u
  JOIN user_organization_role AS uor ON (uor.user_id=u.id)
  JOIN event_sponsor AS es ON (es.organization_id=uor.organization_id)
  WHERE
    e.id=$event_id AND
    uor.term_to >= CURRENT_DATE() AND
    u.netid='{$netid}'      
UNION
  SELECT count(*)
  FROM user AS u
  JOIN user_organization_role AS uor ON (uor.user_id=u.id)
  JOIN project_sponsor AS ps ON (ps.organization_id=uor.organization_id)        
  WHERE
    uer.event_id=$event_id AND
    uor.term_to >= CURRENT_DATE() AND
    u.netid='{$netid}'
```

Is this the best approach? Is there a way to simplify it?

Comment: I changed the store proc in my answer. Please try it again !!!

Comment: I added another stored procedure that does not use the UNION clause.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using a [Stored Function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-routines.html) ?

You can split the union into your individual queries and if it passes any one of the three, return count(*). Otherwise, return 0

Some [restrictions on stored functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-program-restrictions.html)

I recommended function over procedure because it's invoked like:

```
SELECT myfunc(userID, eventID);
```

and your query doesn't look like it needs a resultset returned, just a single value. If it needs a resultset, you would need a procedure (as noted in the restrictions documentation)

Answer (score 3):

Here is your original UNION query

```
SELECT count(*)
  FROM user AS u
  JOIN user_event_role AS uer ON (uer.user_id=u.id)
  WHERE
    uer.event_id=$event_id AND
    uer.term_to >= CURRENT_DATE() AND
    uer.role != 'volunteer' AND
    u.netid='{$netid}'
UNION
  SELECT count(*)
  FROM user AS u
  JOIN user_project_role AS upr ON (upr.user_id=u.id)
  JOIN event AS e ON (e.project_id=upr.project_id)
  WHERE
    e.id=$event_id AND
    upr.term_to >= CURRENT_DATE() AND
    u.netid='{$netid}'                      
UNION
  SELECT count(*)
  FROM user AS u
  JOIN user_organization_role AS uor ON (uor.user_id=u.id)
  JOIN event_sponsor AS es ON (es.organization_id=uor.organization_id)
  WHERE
    e.id=$event_id AND
    uor.term_to >= CURRENT_DATE() AND
    u.netid='{$netid}'      
UNION
  SELECT count(*)
  FROM user AS u
  JOIN user_organization_role AS uor ON (uor.user_id=u.id)
  JOIN project_sponsor AS ps ON (ps.organization_id=uor.organization_id)        
  WHERE
    uer.event_id=$event_id AND
    uor.term_to >= CURRENT_DATE() AND
    u.netid='{$netid}'
```

You need to make three changes.

1. Count the distinct userids
2. Refactor each subquery on the inline subquery for users
3. Index the tables to better support the term_to columns

Here is the Refactored Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id
FROM (
SELECT u.id
  FROM (SELECT id FROM user WHERE netid='{$netid}') AS u
  JOIN user_event_role AS uer ON (uer.user_id=u.id)
  WHERE
    uer.event_id=$event_id AND
    uer.term_to >= CURRENT_DATE() AND
    uer.role != 'volunteer'
UNION
  SELECT u.id
  FROM (SELECT id FROM user WHERE netid='{$netid}') AS u
  JOIN user_project_role AS upr ON (upr.user_id=u.id)
  JOIN event AS e ON (e.project_id=upr.project_id)
  WHERE
    e.id=$event_id AND
    upr.term_to >= CURRENT_DATE()           
UNION
  SELECT u.id
  FROM (SELECT id FROM user WHERE netid='{$netid}') AS u
  JOIN user_organization_role AS uor ON (uor.user_id=u.id)
  JOIN event_sponsor AS es ON (es.organization_id=uor.organization_id)
  WHERE
    e.id=$event_id AND
    uor.term_to >= CURRENT_DATE()
UNION
  SELECT u.id
  FROM (SELECT id FROM user WHERE netid='{$netid}') AS u
  JOIN user_organization_role AS uor ON (uor.user_id=u.id)
  JOIN project_sponsor AS ps ON (ps.organization_id=uor.organization_id)        
  WHERE
    uer.event_id=$event_id AND
    uor.term_to >= CURRENT_DATE()
) userids ORDER BY id;
```

Here are the Indexes You Need to Speed Up the Subqueries:

```
ALTER TABLE user_event_role ADD INDEX (event_id,term_to,role);
ALTER TABLE user_project_role ADD INDEX (term_to);
ALTER TABLE user_organization_role ADD INDEX (term_to);
```

Interestingly, @DTest gave a good idea in his answer. Make a Stored Function. However you have to pass in three parameters: NetID,UserID,EventID. Here is that Stored Function DoesUserHaveEditPrivs using the new refactored query:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS DoesUserHaveEditPrivs $$
CREATE FUNCTION DoesUserHaveEditPrivs
(GivenNetID INT,GivenUserID INT,GivenEventID INT) RETURNS INT
BEGIN

  DECLARE rv INT;
  DECLARE UserID_Tag VARCHAR(32);
  DECLARE UserID_CSV VARCHAR(1024);

  SET rv = 1;
  SELECT idlist INTO UserID_CSV FROM (
    SELECT CONCAT('.',GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT id SEPARATOR '.'),'.') idlist
    FROM (
      SELECT u.id
      FROM (SELECT id FROM user WHERE netid=GivenNetID) AS u
      JOIN user_event_role AS uer ON (uer.user_id=u.id)
      WHERE
        uer.event_id=GivenEventID AND
        uer.term_to >= CURRENT_DATE() AND
        uer.role != 'volunteer'
    UNION
      SELECT u.id
      FROM (SELECT id FROM user WHERE netid=GivenNetID) AS u
      JOIN user_project_role AS upr ON (upr.user_id=u.id)
      JOIN event AS e ON (e.project_id=upr.project_id)
      WHERE
        e.id=GivenEventID AND
        upr.term_to >= CURRENT_DATE()
    UNION
      SELECT u.id
      FROM (SELECT id FROM user WHERE netid=GivenNetID) AS u
      JOIN user_organization_role AS uor ON (uor.user_id=u.id)
      JOIN event_sponsor AS es ON (es.organization_id=uor.organization_id)
      WHERE
        e.id=GivenEventID AND
        uor.term_to >= CURRENT_DATE()
    UNION
      SELECT u.id
      FROM (SELECT id FROM user WHERE netid=GivenNetID) AS u
      JOIN user_organization_role AS uor ON (uor.user_id=u.id)
      JOIN project_sponsor AS ps ON (ps.organization_id=uor.organization_id)
      WHERE
        uer.event_id=GivenEventID AND
        uor.term_to >= CURRENT_DATE()
    ) userids_unioned ORDER BY id
  ) userids;

  SET UserID_Tag = CONCAT('.',GivenUserID,'.');

  IF LOCATE(UserID_Tag,UserID_CSV) THEN
    SET rv = 0;
  END IF;

  RETURN rv;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Here is what the Stored Function Does: It first creates a period separated list of Unique UserIDs from the Refactored Query called UserID_CSV using the [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function. An extra period is prepended and appended to UserID_CSV. It then creates another variable called UserID_Tag which has a string contains the GivenUserID surrounded by periods. I then use the [LOCATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) function to get the index position of the UserID_Tag as located in UserID_CSV. If LOCATE returns 0, function returns 0. Otherwise, it returns 1.

Give it a Try !!! (@DTest, +1 for suggesting the Stored Function)

UPDATE 2011-05-28 18:00

I find your error unusual since I create the storted procedure in MySQL Query Browser with no compiler errors. I changed the code to put the UNION queries in another subquery. Try it again, please !!!

UPDATE 2011-05-28 17:52

I have an alternate solution via the stored procedure. I eliminated the use of UNION and piled up unique ids in a temp table:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS DoesUserHaveEditPrivs $$
CREATE FUNCTION DoesUserHaveEditPrivs
(GivenNetID INT,GivenUserID INT,GivenEventID INT) RETURNS INT
BEGIN

  DECLARE rv INT;
  DECLARE UserID_Tag VARCHAR(32);
  DECLARE UserID_CSV VARCHAR(1024);

  DROP TABLE IF EXIST idlist;
  CREATE TEMPORARY sfTABLE idlist (id INT,PRIMARY KEY (ID)) ENGINE=MEMORY;
  SET rv = 1;
  INSERT IGNORE INTO idlist
  SELECT id FROM (
      SELECT u.id
      FROM (SELECT id FROM user WHERE netid=GivenNetID) AS u
      JOIN user_event_role AS uer ON (uer.user_id=u.id)
      WHERE
        uer.event_id=GivenEventID AND
        uer.term_to >= CURRENT_DATE() AND
        uer.role != 'volunteer'
  );
  INSERT IGNORE INTO idlist
  SELECT id FROM (
      SELECT u.id
      FROM (SELECT id FROM user WHERE netid=GivenNetID) AS u
      JOIN user_project_role AS upr ON (upr.user_id=u.id)
      JOIN event AS e ON (e.project_id=upr.project_id)
      WHERE
        e.id=GivenEventID AND
        upr.term_to >= CURRENT_DATE()
  );
  INSERT IGNORE INTO idlist
  SELECT id FROM (
      SELECT u.id
      FROM (SELECT id FROM user WHERE netid=GivenNetID) AS u
      JOIN user_organization_role AS uor ON (uor.user_id=u.id)
      JOIN event_sponsor AS es ON (es.organization_id=uor.organization_id)
      WHERE
        e.id=GivenEventID AND
        uor.term_to >= CURRENT_DATE()
  );
  INSERT IGNORE INTO idlist
  SELECT id FROM (
      SELECT u.id
      FROM (SELECT id FROM user WHERE netid=GivenNetID) AS u
      JOIN user_organization_role AS uor ON (uor.user_id=u.id)
      JOIN project_sponsor AS ps ON (ps.organization_id=uor.organization_id)
      WHERE
        uer.event_id=GivenEventID AND
        uor.term_to >= CURRENT_DATE()
  ;
  SELECT CONCAT('.',GROUP_CONCAT(id SEPARATOR '.'),'.') FROM idlist;

  SET UserID_Tag = CONCAT('.',GivenUserID,'.');

  IF LOCATE(UserID_Tag,UserID_CSV) THEN
    SET rv = 0;
  END IF;

  RETURN rv;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: @DTest, thanks for suggesting a Stored Function. That should speed it up a lot.

Comment: thanks for your work in refactoring the query and then converting it to a Stored Function. Something I'm wondering about: The UserID parameter to the function. That information isn't available until the query finds the UserId for the user who has the NetID.

Comment: I tried it and got the following error: "Incorrect usage of UNION and INTO".

Comment: @dac Did the error come from making the stored function or running it ? What version of MySQL are you running ?

Answer (score 2):

This is the perfect situation for using **Views**. I'd create a view called **viewEditableEvents** which filters only those events that can be edited by leaders. Then you can write your SQL query against the view.

Comment: this may solve an upcoming problem. If I create a view for everything a user can edit (events, projects, organizations), then I check the view to see whether this user can edit the particular event, project, or organization. A view brings all the data together to make queries easy from both directions: (starting with netid only or with netid and one of the following--event_id, project_id, or organization_id). Maybe use it with a stored function that passes in the relevant id's.